# How To Create Two User Groups in Firebase Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am developing a web app which uses Firebase Authentication and Real-time Database. The sign-in method is via Google and then if the user is new he/she will be ask if whether he/she is a teacher or student.

**Teacher:** can create classrooms and add students using their user.uid. Each classroom has a unique classroom id. Can view the list of their students.

**Student:** can view their classroom, and classmates.

So **How do I code two different types of users in Firebase for my web app?**
What will be the rules to use in the database?

Answer (score 2):

[UPDATED]

You could try this the simple way:

1. Create a *JSON object* to store the users information in a field depends on the usage:

   - a field `isTeacher` of type *boolean* (assume you won't add other user type) or
   - a field `userType` of object contain all the feature types (isTeacher: *boolean*, isStudent: *boolean*, *isHeadmaster:boolean*, etc.) or
   - a field of `userType` of type *string*
2. Create a method or condition to check the field of the user document whether is `true` for a particular user type / `compare string` (depends which one you use) by using `if` or `switch` case
3. Under each case / condition, show the elements of the web according to their privilege.
4. After signed-in, before the page load, do the checking using the function created

Comment: Conceptually, this is a good answer. However, the OP is asking about Firebase *Database* not Firestore. Database has no collections or documents. Also 1) is spot on but the function in 2) is not needed as when the user authenticates, determine the user type by reading that users node via their user uid (e.g. /your_firebase/users/uid/user_type).